# setup proxy on on-prem server on Anypoint Platform

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform, anypoint-api-manager

We have some application those are build in some other programing languages and for those API I need to setup proxy on on-prem server.

We can do this in API Manager in Anypoint Platform but how we can do the same in case of on-prem standalone server?

Answer (score 1):

API Manager can manage REST APIs by deploying an autogenerated proxy application. API Manager can deploy it either to CloudHub or to your standalone Mule server that is registered in Runtime Manager. The documentation has a [step by step guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/manage-exchange-api-task).

Comment: Be sure to allocate license cores to the standalone server so that the API gateway license entitlement is available for the on premise server (tip from experience).  This will generate a new license file to install if you didn't do it before.